# How to put a timer on x number of pictures (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a code that changes the picture that is displayed every time a button is clicked. However, I need the code to to put the pictures on a timer so that the button only needs to be clicked once and the pictures will be displayed with equal intervals of time between them.

I have been trying to do some research into timers on JavaScript but I cant seem to find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: store an array of image urls, use setInterval to swap between the images every X seconds, once the button is clicked, you can then change the button to clear the interval and stop the looping of images if its clicked again or if you run out of images

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't quite make it work but I'll play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

example of comment (you will see it flicker because no actual image urls), if you want nice fading in and out of images, I would recommend to check out jQuery.fadeTo

```js
function rotateImages() {
    var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'];
    var imageEle = document.getElementById('image_id');
    var imageInterval = setInterval(swapImage, 2000);
    var i = 0;
    function swapImage(){
     if(i === images.length - 1){
       clearInterval(imageInterval);
     }
     imageEle.src = images[i];
     i++; 
    }    
}
```

```html
<img id="image_id" src="image.jpg">
<button onclick='rotateImages();'>Rotate Images</button>
```